# Access typescript uniontype inside array type

Tags: typescript

I'm actually not event sure how to phrase the question correctly. From a code generator I get the following interface as an input for an API request:

```ts
interface foo {
  bar: ('foo' | 'bar')[] 
}
```

To access this I can create aliases like `type xy = foo['bar']`. But I actually have no idea how to get a type that includes the union inside an array. I want to have a type `type union = 'foo' | 'bar'` by referencing the interface.

I already tried to use index anotation like `type union = foo['bar'][string]` or `type union = foo['bar'][number]` but that throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually the issue I had was a bit different and is missing in my example.

If you have

```ts
interface Foo {
  bar?: ('foo' | 'bar')[] 
}
```

Then `type BarOrFoo = Foo['bar'][number]; // "bar" | "foo"` will not work.

But instead the following works

```ts
type BarOrFoo = Exclude<Foo['bar'], undefined>[number]
```

Comment: New question information belongs in the question content.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by accessing the `bar` property via interface property access notation: `foo["bar"]`, then access the item union by indexing with `number` to get the type of the items.  Here is the full code:

```
interface foo {
  bar: ('foo' | 'bar')[] 
}

type FooBarItem = foo["bar"][number];
//   ^? "bar" | "foo"
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAhgezcg3gKGcgIzigC5kAKAcnTUuQB9lKipKBKAbQF1kcBfHDjABPAA4oAYhgBCxAJKQAtsgC8qDBwBELTVw4gArooLQuAbhwB6S-mQA9APzJtxTQ2c1NQA)

Answer (score -1):

*Update based on [new information you presented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71547483/438273):*

Because the property is optional, you can use the type utility [`NonNullable<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) to exclude `null` and `undefined` from its union. Then, you can use an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html#handbook-content) (`number` in this case to access elements in an array, which are indexed by number keys).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyyARnFAPwBcyAFAOQyZ3IA+ydpUdAlANoC6AbgIBfAgTABPAA4oAQmQDyUDFgC8yAHLoQmgK4AbA3GIGIAHlW8OZOvwB8vEHoC2xaEOQB6L8gBEnH6s-ozofgRAA)

```ts
interface Foo {
  bar?: ('foo' | 'bar')[];
}

type BarOrFoo = NonNullable<Foo['bar']>[number]; // "bar" | "foo"
```